# mysql/mariadb strict_trans_table mode. Log before enabling

Tags: mysql, mariadb, legacy-code, legacy-database

I have an older legacy application running a old version of MariaDB(10.1). Before doing an upgrade i would like to make sure i "catch" all the insertion fails, auto-truncation etc.

I've been searching for a way to log all of these events so that i can go through them and make the nessesary changes either in the schema or in the application code.

The only thing i've found so far have been how to disable strict_trans_table entirely, which is not what i want.

Thanks.
(was not able to create strict_trans_table tag)